# Rails : Return an object to show user's profile completeness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a User Model and would like to return to the controller and view what parts of the user's profile are complete and what parts are not.

So it would return for example an object "profile_completeness" which can be used like so :

```
@user.profile_completeness.personal_info
```

Which would be true if the particular part of the profile was filled.

What I tried :

```
def profile_completeness
    if self.name.present?  && self.email.present?
        profile_completeness.personal_info = true
    end
    return profile_completeness
end
```

I got the error :

```
 SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Am I going about this the right way? If not, what do you think is the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call set the .personal_info=true on the method itself. In such situation I'd just use either [Hashes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html).

```
def profile_completeness
  ret = Hash.new
  if self.name.present?  && self.email.present?
    ret[:personal_info] = true
  end
  ret
end
```

Or even better I'd prefer different method for each of the 'completeness' part:

```
def personal_info_complete?
  ....
end
```